# About the proof of $\overline{\prod A_{\alpha}}\subset \prod\overline A_{\alpha}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I found this proof here [products of closure, is the closure of the product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50766/products-of-closure-is-the-closure-of-the-product)

> Conversely, suppose that $x = (x_\alpha)$ lies in the closure of $\prod_\alpha A_\alpha$ in either the box or the product topology on $\prod_\alpha X_\alpha$. We show that for any given index $\beta$ we have $x_\beta \in \overline{A_\beta}$. Let $V_\beta$ be an arbitrary open set of $X_\beta$ containing $x_\beta$. Since $\pi_\beta^{-1}$ applied to $V_\beta$ is open in either topology, **it contains a point $y$ of $\prod_\alpha A_\alpha$.**
>
> By definition $\pi_\beta^{-1}[V_\beta] = \{y = (y_\alpha) \in \prod_{\alpha}X_\alpha:y_\beta \in V_\beta\}$; as Stephen said, this is simply $\prod_\alpha V_\alpha$, where $V_\alpha = X_\alpha$ if $\alpha \ne \beta$. This set is open in both the box and the product topologies on $\prod_\alpha X_\alpha$, and it contains $x \in \overline{\prod_\alpha A_\alpha}$ (since $x_\beta \in V_\beta$), so it must contain some point $y \in \prod_\alpha A_\alpha$: the fact that $x \in \overline{\prod_\alpha A_\alpha}$ means by definition that every open nbhd of $x$ must contain some point of $\prod_\alpha A_\alpha$.

I'm having problem understanding the
bold text and also I don't see the conclusion of the proof, I mean the ...therefore "for any given index $\beta$ we have $x_\beta \in \overline{A_\beta}$"

Could anyone help me, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re assuming that $x\in\overline{\prod_{\alpha}A_{\alpha}}$ and want to prove that $x_{\beta}\in\overline{A_{\beta}}$ for each $\beta$.

Let $V_{\beta}$ be an open subset of $X_{\beta}$ that contains $x_{\beta}$. Letting $$V\equiv \pi_{\beta}^{-1}(V_{\beta})=V_{\beta}\times\prod_{\alpha\neq\beta}X_{\alpha},$$ it is easy to see that $V$ is an open subset of $\prod_{\alpha}X_{\alpha}$ (in either the product or the box topology). Observe also that $x_{\beta}\in V_{\beta}$ implies that $x\in V$. But since $x$ is also contained in the closure of $\prod_{\alpha}A_{\alpha}$ and $V$ is open, there must exist some $y\in V\cap \prod_{\alpha}A_{\alpha}$. This implies, in particular, that $y_{\beta}\in V_{\beta}\cap A_{\beta}$.

To summarize, what has been shown is that each open set containing $x_{\beta}$ also contains an element of $A_{\beta}$, which implies that $x_{\beta}$ is in the closure of $A_{\beta}$, as claimed.

---

Throughout the proof, we use the following fact:

> Let $X$ be an arbitrary topological space, $A\subseteq X$, and $x\in X$. Then, $x\in\overline{A}$ if and only if every open set $U\subseteq X$ that contains $x$ also contains an element from $A$.

Comment: Why $x_\beta\in V_\beta$ implies that $x\in V$ ?

Comment: @bella Because $V=\pi_{\beta}^{-1}(V_{\beta})$ by definition. Now, note that $x_{\beta}=\pi_{\beta}(x)$ by the definition of coordinate projections. If $x_{\beta}\in V_{\beta}$, then we have that $\pi_{\beta}(x)\in V_{\beta}$, so $x\in\pi_{\beta}^{-1}(V_{\beta})=V$.

Comment: @bella You’re welcome. I’m glad it seems to be clear now. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 1):

1) $\pi_{\beta}^{-1}(V_{\beta})=V_{\beta}\times\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha\ne\beta}X_{\alpha}$ and the latter is an open set in either box or product topology. Now $x\in V_{\beta}\times\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha\ne\beta}X_{\alpha}$, so $\left(V_{\beta}\times\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha\ne\beta}X_{\alpha}\right)\bigcap\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha}A_{\alpha}\ne\emptyset$, and hence $\pi_{\beta}^{-1}(V_{\beta})\bigcap\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha}A_{\alpha}\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: The second one follows by arbitrariness of $\beta$.

Comment: arbitrariness of $\beta$? I don't understand you.

Comment: That means the $\beta$ is fixed by the very beginning and you manage to prove that $x_{\beta}\in\overline{A_{\beta}}$ for this $\beta$, and then you let the $\beta$ varies throughout.

Comment: Right but the $x_\beta\in\overline A_\beta$ appears to mention what has to be proven only.

Comment: Actually the final aim is to prove that $x\in\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha}\overline{A_{\alpha}}$, but this is equivalent to prove in the pointwise coordinate, which we name it as $\beta$, that is, it is equivalent to prove that $x=(x_{\beta})$ is such that $x_{\beta}\in\overline{A_{\beta}}$. The pointwise copy of $\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha}\overline{A_{\alpha}}$ is just $A_{\beta}$. Think of $A_{1}\times A_{2}\times A_{3}$ for example and we pick up $i$ to stand for $1,2,3$ and consider $A_{i}$.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence, "Think of..." why do you try to do?

Comment: Let say how do you prove that $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})\in\overline{A_{1}}\times\overline{A_{2}}\times\overline{A_{3}}$? Essentially you just need to prove that $x_{i}\in\overline{A_{i}}$ for $i=1,2,3$.

Comment: I think I am understanding :) .But first, shouldn't be $x$ instead of $y$ in the bold text?

Comment: That is an element of in the intersection, but the main role is $x$.

Comment: If $x\in\prod A_\alpha$, then $x\in A_\alpha $ and as $x\in\pi_\beta^{-1}[V_\beta],$ then $x\in\overline A_\alpha$. Am I correct?

Comment: Although I don't see why to mix index in the proof, the $\alpha$ and $\beta$..

Comment: You can use $\alpha$ throughout the proof.

Comment: ok, but is my above argument correct?

Comment: Yes, but that seems not help in the argument in question.

Comment: why not? you said that what needs to be proven is $x_i\in\overline A_i$

Comment: But you should assume $x\in\overline{\displaystyle\prod_{i}A_{i}}$ at first, it comes with the bar.

Comment: yes, and then the bold part text comes in the proof, and I asked you if y can be changed by x, so $x\in\prod A_i$

Comment: Actually I don't quite understand your question. Of course, you can swipe the $x$ and $y$.

Comment: "but that seems not help in the argument in question. " why did you said that?

Comment: Okay now I understand what you said, okay, it goes through.

Comment: ? ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Your argument goes through, that's it.